# F# - How to convert array into nativeptr<double>

Tags: f#, interop

I need to interop with some low level C/ FORTAN library. The library requires me to provide a call back function, which has the following signature in C#:

```
public static class Interop
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public unsafe delegate void F(
        ref int neq,
        ref double t,
        double* y,
        double* yDot);
}
```

Variable `neq` contains the lengths of the arrays `y` and `yDot`. The external library will provide pointers to the first elements of these arrays.

I can easily create an F# interop to be consumed by this library, e.g.:

```
let private f (neq : byref<int>, t : byref<double>, x : nativeptr<double>, dx : nativeptr<double>) : unit =

    for i in 0 .. (neq - 1) do
        NativePtr.set dx i (NativePtr.get x i)


let createInterop() = Interop.F(fun n t y dy -> f(&n, &t, y, dy))
```

It works and I can see that the function is being called and does something.

Now, I want to write a test that the interop that I created works correctly.

```
let interopTest() =
    let neq = 10
    let t = 0.0
    let (x : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n
    let (dx : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n
    let interop = createInterop()

    // Call the interop. ! DOES NOT COMPILE !
    do interop.Invoke(ref neq, ref t, x, dx)

    // Verify the results.
```

No matter what tried, the call to `interop.Invoke` does not compile. For the code above, it fails at `x` and `dx` with the message:

```
[FS0001] This expression was expected to have type
    'nativeptr<float>'    
but here has type
    'double []'
```

I can declare `neq` and `t` as mutable and then call the interop like: `interop.Invoke(&neq, &t, ...`. That makes no difference. However, using e.g. `&dx.[0]` produces the same compiler error.

I need to pass the pointers to the first elements of arrays `x` and `dx` to the interop function. Unfortunately searching for how to cast array to a nativeptr in F# did not produce any useful results.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can give the compiler error message and the exact location, it might be easier to tell what the problem is. I'm thinking perhaps `&dx.[0]`, but I could certainly be way off.

Comment: Shouldn't `n` and `t` be mutable? Is`neq` actually `n`? - `neq` is not defined in your test. If mutable, then they should be referred to by `&n` and `&t`?

Comment: I updated the question to show the compiler error message and where it occurs and I also commented about using mutable `t` and `neq` (which was erroneously called `n` before).

Comment: (Looking again maybe these should be reference cells). Anyway if you need `nativeptr` you need to `let (x : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n
    let (dx : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n

    let tx = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<double> x
    let tdx = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<double> dx

    do interop.Invoke(ref neq, ref t, tx.ToPointer(), tdx.ToPointer())` This is not tested, but should help as a guide to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to "how to cast array to a nativeptr in F#":

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop  
    
let private f (neq : byref<int>, t : byref<double>, x : nativeptr<double>, dx : nativeptr<double>) : unit =

    for i in 0 .. (neq - 1) do
        NativePtr.set dx i (NativePtr.get x i)

let createInterop() = fun n t y dy -> f(&n, &t, y, dy))

let interopTest() =
    let n = 10
    let t = 0.0
    let (x : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n
    let (dx : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n

    let tx = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<double> x     
    let tdx = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<double> dx     
   
    let interop = createInterop()

    // Call the interop. Does compile but does not call your c# interop
    // but does create the correct nativeptr(s)
    interop n  t tx tdx

    // Verify the results.
```

**Update:**

Apparently this did not work for the OP but both `tx` and `tdx` produce the same correct type, either way, in VS Code, at least for me. Anyway this shows another interesting way of doing the same thing and maybe others might find that one works when the other does not?

```
let interopTest() =
    let n = 10
    let t = 0.0
    let (x : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n
    let (dx : double[]) = Array.zeroCreate n

    let tx = fixed &x.[0]    // val tx: nativeptr<double>
    let tdx = fixed &dx.[0]  // val tdx: nativeptr<double>

      
    let interop = createInterop()

    // Call the interop.
    do interop.Invoke(ref n, ref t, tx, tdx)

    // Verify the results.
```

Comment: I am getting compile errors on `let tx` and `let tdx`: `[FS0001] This expression was expected to have type 'nativeint' but here has type 'double []'`. I am using NET5 x64 Release build.

Comment: The trick turned out to use: `use tx = fixed &x.[0]` and `use tdx = fixed &dx.[0]`. Then the code compiles and works. If you could, please, update the answer, then I'd be glad to mark it is as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your error was as both methods produce the inferred type nativeptr<double>. Strange. Updated